# ZF axioms on a transitive class

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I am using the book *Set theory* by Kunen (2013 edition, numeration is completely different than the previous ones) and I'm trying to show the following (theorem II.4.27):

> Let $M$ be a transitive class verifying:
>
> 1. Comprehension axiom holds.
> 2. $\forall x\subset M$ there exists $y\in M$ such that $x\subset y$.
>
> Then all ZF axioms hold in M.

I managed to show all axioms (using II.2.4 and II.2.8) except for the axiom on infinity, that is $\omega \in M$, the book says that I should use lemma II.4.10 which is

> $M$ transitive class in BST, then
>
> 1. $[M]^{<\omega}\subset M$
> 2. HF$\subset M$

I'm probably missing something obvious but I really can't see how you do it, it's probably easier to show $\omega\subset M$ (which is enough by (2)) but I haven't managed to do that either.se

Answer (score 1):

You know that $HF\subset M$, so by (2) you know that there is some $y\in M$ with $HF\subseteq y$. Now, you just want to build $\omega$ from $y$.

The obvious problem is that $y$ is "too big" - it contains $HF$ (which is much bigger than $\omega$), and it might contain a lot more than $HF$ (we just know $HF\subseteq y$ not $HF=y$). So we need to "trim" it.

This is where Separation comes into play. There are lots of ways to define the finite ordinals - for example, let $\varphi(x)$ be the formula "$x$ is an ordinal and every ordinal in $x$ is either a successor ordinal or $0$." So apply Separation to $y$ using any such formula; this will give you exactly $\omega$.

Well, that last bit takes proof: you need to argue that the things $M$ thinks are finite ordinals are exactly the finite ordinals. But this isn't hard - you have $HF\subset M$, so clearly the things $M$ thinks are finite ordinals consist of *at least* the actual finite ordinals, and conversely you can use the transitivity of $M$ to show that $M$ doesn't think anything is a finite ordinal that *isn't actually* a finite ordinal.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to try to show that all the finite ordinals are in $M$ by showing that $\emptyset \in M$ and using induction? (this is what I was trying to do, but couldn't get anywhere). I'm going to need a bit of time to think of your method to understand it.

Comment: @Smurf That won't really save you any time. First of all, the induction step isn't completely trivial (my suggestion: given $n\in M$, use Powerset + Separation - look at $\{x\in\mathcal{P}(n):$ $x$ is an ordinal$\}$). More to the point, once you have $\omega\subset M$, (2) gives you $y\in M$ for some $y\supseteq \omega$ - so you *still* have to cut it down, which is what the bulk of my answer consists of. You'll *always* need to do something like this, since (2) has the potential to "overshoot" the set you want.

Comment: @Smurf: Yes, that would be easier. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove by induction: If $\alpha$ is an ordinal and $\alpha\subseteq M$, then $\alpha\in M$. Therefore every ordinal is in $M$, in particular $\omega$ itself.

To see why, let $y\in M$ such that $\alpha\subseteq y$ and use Comprehension to separate the ordinals which are in $y$, namely define $x\in M$ to be $\{u\in y\mid u\text{ is an ordinal}\}$ using Comprehension (here it is important that $M$ is transitive and agrees with the universe on being an ordinal). Either there is some $\gamma\in x$ such that $\alpha<\gamma$ and by the transitive property of $M$ now $\alpha\in M$, or simply $x=\alpha$ and we are done.